# Get enum object from its type passed in a generic

Tags: typescript, generics, enums

This is a simplified example, the idea is a set of tags each one defined by a single char. The object "Flags" accumulates the values
The possible values are defined in an enum.
The objective is to have the source explicit, concise, refactorizable, verified by the compiler and the object storing the flags compact (for database storage)

```
class Flags<ENU>{
    s: string = "";
    set(v: ENU){
        this.s += v;
        return this;
    }
    has(v: ENU){
        return this.s.includes(v);
    }
}

enum TypeAnimal{
    Winged = "w",
    Legged = "l"
}

let flagsBird = new Flags<TypeAnimal>().set(TypeAnimal.Winged);
```

I want to verify that the enums that go through this have no duplicated values.
I thought one possibility would be passing the type not as a generic explicitly but as a parameter in the constructor and let ts infer the generic. it seems to almost work:

```
class Flags2<ENU>{
    s: string = "";
    constructor(enu: ENU){
        // check here the values in enu, fine.
    }
    set(v: ENU){
        this.s += v;    
        return this;
    }
    has(v: ENU){
        return this.s.includes(v);
    }
}

let flagsBird2 = new Flags2(TypeAnimal);
```

but this gives an error:

```
flagsBird2.set(TypeAnimal.Winged);    // Argument of type 'TypeAnimal' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof TypeAnimal'.ts(2345)
```

I've tried some typeof combinations around (a bit blindly I must admit) that didn't work.

Any ideas or thoughts? (I think that here I have something to learn about ts and generics)

Comment: I understand that it's a simplified example but have you considered using a Set?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 1):

What benefit does this shortened encoding really give you?

IMO, enums in TypeScript aren't really worth it.

The idomatic way to solve this is to use types (remember, types can be strings), not enums. The `Set` class gives you duplicate removal for free.

```
class Flags3<T extends string>{
    s: Set<string> = new Set();
    constructor(enu: readonly T[]) {
        // check here the values in enu, fine.
    }
    set(v: T) {
        this.s.add(v)
        return this;
    }
    has(v: T) {
        return this.s.has(v);
    }
}

// parameter type below is ("legged" | "winged")[], NOT string[]
const f3 = new Flags3(["legged", "winged"]);

// or
// const animalTypes=["legged","winged"] as const;
// const f3 = new Flags3(animalTypes)

f3.set("legged"); // OK
f3.set("foo"); // compile time error
```

By specifying `readonly T[]` in the constructor parameter, we are able to infer the individual types in the tuple that is passed to it.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBi4HMIGYA8AVaBTAHgFywDsATGCPAJwEtCEA+AbwChpXoIAuaAZSz1XLVadaAF5ohLAHcefABQBKANws2wAPaFBAV2B51FOUW1cKWMMU0gAntHQBtALoLozNu+gB6T9GAALLGAAa2gAs2g8AOgANzAQbSwYGmxCbQAaaAAzGiwAOlVWAF8C9nlornQXNw9WSKoIXIaLYjlohRL3MzxtCkIIv3qVd2L3P0hWiqqOti6evrqGhrGIVuUS4uKmDS08LOQxCWk4RBQ5ewAiECwEBCxic4zzqRpb++cVJm9oA0+fbfJoGBCFQALZxdDWAAOiVEFyuNzuDyeL0RjkBMH+eBUX0xewOkhk8DASGQciBoPBUMS7SYmWQjXkl2ur3Oyi8PgA8gBpWn0iCMzLqdSspTs3zqEGQqhXCKgrDYCgUH5AA)

[Further reading about the downsides of enum](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-trouble-with-typescript-enums)

Comment: I missed one of the main objectives, compactness (for database storage) . Anyway thanks because I see this is refactorizable (changing the string-flag names)

Answer (score 0):

```
enum TypeAnimal{
    Winged = "w",
    Legged = "l"
}

// modified class from the question
class Flags2<ENU>{
    s: string = "";
    set(v: ENU){
        this.s += v;    // #todo avoid duplicates in this.s
        return this;
    }
    has(v: ENU){
        return this.s.includes(`${v}`);
    }
}

// version with a Set instead of a string. No duplicates.
class Flags3<ENU>{
    s: Set<ENU> = new Set();
    set(v: ENU){
        this.s.add(v);
        return this;
    }
    has(v: ENU){
        return this.s.has(v);
    }
}

let flagsBird2 = new Flags2<TypeAnimal>();
let flagsBird3 = new Flags3<TypeAnimal>();
```